# How i compute the determinant of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix such that $A^{-1}=I-2A$. I want to compute the determinant $A$. I can reply to the question if $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix. Since from $A^{-1}=I-2A$ deduce that $A^{2}-1/2A+1/2I=0$. IF $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial $A$, then $p(x)=x^{2}-1/2x+1/2$. Hence the characteristics polynomial of $A$ is $x^{2}-1/2x+1/2$. So $detA=1/2$.

Comment: Since $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, its characteristic polynomial will have degree 3, so the quadratic polynomial that $A$ satisfies above is not its characteristic polynomial.  Are we to assume that $A$ is a real matrix?

Comment: @hardmath You say that there is not such a matrix?

Comment: There is not such a real $3\times 3$ matrix that satisfies $A^{-1} = I - 2A$, but there are complex matrices that satisfy this.  The characteristic polynomial of a $3\times 3$ matrix is a third degree polynomial, whether real or complex.

Comment: You can let $A$ be a complex matrix. What is detA?

Comment: You need more information.  If the matrix $A$ is *real* and $2\times 2$, the polynomial $p(x)$ shown in your Question must be the characteristic polynomial (because the two roots are complex, and so this must also be the minimal polynomial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ satisfies the above equation, its eigenvalues should satisfy $p(x)$. But $p(x)$ has only two complex conjugate roots, therefore $A$ is not a real matrix. If it was its 3rd eigenvalue should be real, which does not satisfy $p(x)$.

Let $A$ be a complex matrix, so its eigenvalues are $\lambda \in \{ \frac{1+i\sqrt{7}}{4} , \frac{1-i\sqrt{7}}{4}\}$. So $\det(A)$ may be one of the $\lambda^3$, $\lambda^2 \overline{\lambda}$, $\lambda (\overline{\lambda})^2$ or $(\overline{\lambda})^3$, where $\lambda = \frac{1+i\sqrt{7}}{4}$ and $\overline{\lambda}$ is the complex conjugate of $\lambda$.